# Python 3, Copy specific column from one csv file to another csv

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I am just trying to copy an entire column of data from a file called `"solar.csv"` to another csv file called `"current.csv"`. This column I am trying to copy is #14.

Ideally after copying, I would like to output the entire `"current.csv"` file to another directory altogether. Here is what I have so far:

```
with open('F:\somefolder\somedata\solar.csv', 'rb') as f, open('F:\somefolder\somedata\current.csv', 'wb') as f_out:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow((row[14]))
```

Comment: `(row[14])` does not create a tuple. Did you mean to use `[row[14]]` or `(row[14],)` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the csv module, but reading a csv file should be easy. Like

```
with open('solar.csv', 'r') as f, open('current.csv', 'w') as f_out:
  for line in f:
    cols = line.split(',', 14)
    if len(cols) >= 14:
      f_out.write(cols[13].strip() + "\n")
```